# At least 1000 of the X-elements have a value for the attribute Y

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have this Xml Schema that validates some XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="organisation">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="objid" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="parent_objid" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
            <xs:attribute name="stext" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="U">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="NAME" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="USER_" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="RBS" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I need to tighten the validation such that the XML fragment is only valid if there are at least 1000 (or some other number) of the `U`-elements that have a non-empty value for the `RBS`-attribute.

Can this be done using standard W3C XSD schemas?